# What tool can be used to MIGRATE SQL Server DB/DW to Azure Synapse (formerly Azure SQL DW)?

Tags: azure-synapse

We are trying to migrate our sql server datamart to Azure synapse. I saw we can use Azure DMA for migrating SQL DB to Azure DB or Azure DB Managed instance, But I do not see any option to migrate it to Azure Synapse(formerly Azure SQL DW). Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand , you can use the copy activity in ADF to achieve this . I assuming that you have a SQL Server in-premis server , if thats the case you will also have to use self hosted integration service ( SHIR ) . More on the copy activty [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#supported-data-stores-and-formats)